# Why does the loop loop itself when "else" is triggered? Is this because of things called memory allocation?

Tags: c++, char

I'm just a beginner and trying out some code that my teacher taught us to use and things from the textbook.

This program is designed to be for the user to enter in their name and enter in the password as what the system asks them to put down.

Can somebody explain to me why this loop keeps looping itself infinitely when `else` is triggered?

Also, what does the cin.ignore do to the memory of the char name?  Why is 80 better than 20?

AND, why aren't the random numbers actually random? Every time I run it, the numbers are the same.

Thank you all so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
char name[20];
int pwd, rand1, rand2;
for (int i=0;i<1; i++)
    {

    cout<<"Name:               ";
    cin.get(name, 20);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout<<endl;

        srand(rand() % 1000);
        rand1 = (rand() % 21);
        rand2 = (rand()%6);
        cout<<"Password: "<<rand1<<"*"<<rand2<<"=  "; 
        cin>>pwd;

        if(pwd == rand1*rand2)
        { 
            cout<<endl<<"Welcome to our main page, "<<name<<"."<<endl;
        }

        else 
        {
            cout<<"Wrong password, type again." <<endl;
            i--;
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about asking one question? And `rand` being random depends on seeding it correctly, for example, with the current time. Read docs for an example of that.

Comment: I feel like I would spam the post area if I used several posts for several questions.  Keeping it all together would take up less space on the front page.  I'm new here and ... don't know the rules yet :D

Comment: Seeding the generator for `rand()` by calling `srand()` with a seed of `rand()` is somewhat akin to expecting a date to put out before you bought her dinner, don't you think? That `srand()` belongs at the top of `main()` invoked *once* with a proper seed ( `time(NULL)` is common enough to be a worthy consideration).

Comment: if you teacher gave you such a piece of code he doesnt seem to know what hes talking about. This is basically a defacement of a for-loop; usually any reasonable men will take a while-loop for such a task; its completely unclear here whats the intention of the code until one read it to the end.

Comment: Is there some better way to have different seeds in different runs?

Comment: @user2714524 See Paul Drapers answere: One usually takes the time / current tick

Comment: @user2714524 You don't *want* different seeds for different loop iterations. Its a RNG. You want it seeded *once* per process run, and that seed should be unique to other local process runs. Thus the usage of a system time/tick-count being so common. And honestly, if this is C++11, you want to use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in the first place.

Comment: answer to the question on the title: Because when you i--, the i in the for loop keeps decreasing and then increasing. Why are you not using an infinite while loop with break statement?

Comment: @Gasim because the intention of his teacher was apparently to build some kind of Rube Goldberg machine of code.

Comment: For God sake laddie - strap yourself down!! You're in deep dark seas now - and there be *monsters* here :))))

Comment: @WhozCraig +1 for C++11 random.

Comment: @Paranix Actually I was just trying out different codes, and it has nothing to do with my teacher.

Comment: @whozcraig All I want is different random numbers every loop, is that possible?  I have played with python a little before, and it seems like it should be possible.  Can you give a suggestion?

Comment: @user2714524 You'll get them so long as you properly seed the RNG *once*. Its job is to provide the random sequence beyond that; not yours. Do as I said. Seed *once* as soon as you enter `main()` such as `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));`, and *never* again. There is no need to continually reseed, and in fact it defeats the purpose of the RNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up formatting of code will help you understand better. 
Also avoid using namespace std, its bad practice and clutters the global scope with names. Instead use using std::xxxx if you dont want to write std::cout, std::cin, etc every time.

Reformatted code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main () 
{
    char name[20];
    int pwd, rand1, rand2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cout << "Name:               ";
        cin.get(name, 20);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;

        srand(rand() % 1000);
        rand1 = (rand() % 21);
        rand2 = (rand() % 6);
        cout << "Password: " << rand1 << "*" << rand2 << "=  "; 
        cin >> pwd;
        cin.ignore();

        if(pwd == rand1*rand2) { 
            cout << endl << "Welcome to our main page, " << name << "." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Wrong password, type again." << endl;
            i--;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Secondly as you can see in the above code the line cin.ignore(); has been added after cin >> pwd.  Before your code was getting cin >> name, leaving '\n' in the input, ignoring '\n', getting cin >> pwd, leaving '\n' in input, looping and reading input as empty with a '\n', leaving another '\n' in input, first '\n' is removed by ci.ignore(), second '\n' read by cin >> pwd, ... etc. Or at least this is how I understand it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes much more sense now!

Comment: But how can I make the numbers generated be different each run?

Comment: @user2714524 by doing as I said (twice now). This code may be correct for output or skipping data as you desire, but it is utterly incorrect regarding seeding the library RNG in a C/C++ program correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Somebody has answered the first question:Because when you i--, the i in the for loop keeps decreasing and then increasing.-By Gasim 
Then, if your input is longer than 20, the program may stop. So you need cin.ignore(80, '\n') to ignore the excess input. The number 80 is just a big number. You can replace it with another number-only if it's big enough.
You are supposed to use srand with time. `srand(time(null))` may help.

Comment: `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is even better...

Comment: I don't get why i-- would make the loop keep repeating. Wouldn't a i-- at the end and a i++ with the for loop make it work?